Why Camera2D (or viewport) is not moving in Godot 4?
I created the main level scene of my game and it was working until I worked the title scene and the transition. I have a Camera2D node with a simple script:
extends Camera2D
@export var desCentrar := 650
@export var player : CharacterBody2D
func _process(delta):
position.x = player.position.x + desCentrar

print(position.x)

This are the camera settings:
Camera Settings
Any guide is really appreciated!!!
When printing the position, it shows the camera is moving, but in viewport it is not moving. I guess may be I changed some setting in the display project settings when I worked in the main title screen and the transition. I checked the project settings but couldn’t solve the problem.
EDIT:
ok, I tried cahnging the window project settings taking the resolution and scale to a half. when done this, and playing the game since the title screen, the main level starts and the camera makes a jump to then start moving (sometimes). I see the jump is taking the initial view in the viewport and jump to the camera view. Like the camera is not loaded for a frew seconds.
Is there a way to preload the camera node?

Could you open the .tscn file in text format and share the relevant portion?  I've seen strange behavior happen as a result of errors in the scene file itself, especially if you have a tool script that may have modified it unexpectedly.

This is the tscn file in txt:

So, I solved this problem. When the transition scene and the main scene overlaps, the cameras in the scenes creates an issue. When the transition scene is showing the main scene in the transparent parts, is using the transition scene camera, and ignores the main scene camera. When the transition scene is deleted (queue_free()) thecamera jumps to the position of the camera in the main scene.
I solved it eerasing od disabeling the camera in the transition scene and the problem was "solved" at least until I need to change resolution settings and need the camera to reframe the transition.
I stil don't know why it affected the main scene camera when it was executed on play active scene. But it got solved too.
I don't know if this is useful for @ZapTap,but next is the main scene in txt format (I don't know how to use this data, I'm new to Godot:
[gd_scene load_steps=23 format=3 uid="uid://bsf2o7tbx7jf4"]

[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://ctpj7vutf8x8t" path="res://Player/Player.tscn" id="1_ucvfk"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://celueydse0ha7" path="res://Assets/platform_big.tscn" id="2_km684"]
[ext_resource type="Script" path="res://Scripts/Camera2D.gd" id="4_1eqss"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://bvcblmp3arcru" path="res://Assets/platform_small.tscn" id="4_s304j"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://c5lm07yh2k1od" path="res://Assets/BackGround.tscn" id="5_f58ky"]
[ext_resource type="Script" path="res://Scripts/Eraser.gd" id="5_mtntl"]
[ext_resource type="Script" path="res://Scripts/DieZone.gd" id="7_8lb55"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://can3i0w42b5j3" path="res://Assets/ItemGenerator.tscn" id="7_8tphp"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://c6flqyyver72a" path="res://Assets/generador.tscn" id="8_0jbxy"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://e6me4r5mvkna" path="res://Assets/sparks_up.tscn" id="9_kegdm"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://e0jucg1w6dji" path="res://Assets/puntaje.tscn" id="9_qlkeu"]
[ext_resource type="Script" path="res://Scripts/sparks_up.gd" id="10_yihnu"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://dbpqyfxsyfy72" path="res://Assets/Items/Beef.tscn" id="13_xd71t"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://weueemnh2v05" path="res://Assets/Items/Celula.tscn" id="14_kf4ss"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://5c6li8r0f757" path="res://Assets/Items/Leg.tscn" id="15_r6vdc"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://bvcvsjon3p1ji" path="res://Assets/Items/Lengua.tscn" id="16_iye50"]
[ext_resource type="Script" path="res://Scripts/gameTimer.gd" id="17_kjjac"]
[ext_resource type="PackedScene" uid="uid://cgiqvhojh0520" path="res://Player/Player_Musc.tscn" id="18_kdfe2"]

[sub_resource type="RectangleShape2D" id="RectangleShape2D_slslj"]
size = Vector2(2151, 165.5)

[sub_resource type="RectangleShape2D" id="RectangleShape2D_fe4jy"]
size = Vector2(416.512, 20)

[sub_resource type="RectangleShape2D" id="RectangleShape2D_ay8dg"]
size = Vector2(229.466, 20)

[sub_resource type="RectangleShape2D" id="RectangleShape2D_c845b"]
size = Vector2(227, 2912)

[node name="MainLevel" type="Node2D"]

[node name="Platform_big" parent="." instance=ExtResource("2_km684")]
position = Vector2(1158, 989)
scale = Vector2(1.315, 1.315)

[node name="platform_small" parent="." instance=ExtResource("4_s304j")]
position = Vector2(2737, 962)
scale = Vector2(1.315, 1.315)

[node name="platform_small2" parent="." instance=ExtResource("4_s304j")]
position = Vector2(3770, 962)
scale = Vector2(1.315, 1.315)

[node name="platform_small3" parent="." instance=ExtResource("4_s304j")]
position = Vector2(4796, 962)
scale = Vector2(1.315, 1.315)

[node name="ParallaxBackground" parent="." instance=ExtResource("5_f58ky")]

[node name="Player" parent="." instance=ExtResource("1_ucvfk")]
z_index = 2
z_as_relative = false
y_sort_enabled = true
position = Vector2(441, 796)
scale = Vector2(0.376, 0.376)
SPEED = 400.0
gravity = 3500

[node name="Beef" parent="." instance=ExtResource("13_xd71t")]
position = Vector2(865, 796)

[node name="Celula" parent="." instance=ExtResource("14_kf4ss")]
position = Vector2(1060, 823)

[node name="Leg" parent="." instance=ExtResource("15_r6vdc")]
position = Vector2(1264, 823)

[node name="Lengua" parent="." instance=ExtResource("16_iye50")]
position = Vector2(1596, 819)

[node name="gameTimer" type="Timer" parent="."]
unique_name_in_owner = true
one_shot = true
script = ExtResource("17_kjjac")

[node name="Player2" parent="." instance=ExtResource("18_kdfe2")]
visible = false
position = Vector2(611, 801)
scale = Vector2(0.395, 0.395)

[node name="Camera2D" type="Camera2D" parent="." node_paths=PackedStringArray("player")]
show_behind_parent = true
top_level = true
z_index = 3
position = Vector2(960, 540)
scale = Vector2(0.999998, 0.999998)
script = ExtResource("4_1eqss")
player = NodePath("../Player")

[node name="Limits" type="Node2D" parent="Camera2D"]
position = Vector2(-961, -541)

[node name="LimitUp" type="StaticBody2D" parent="Camera2D/Limits"]
position = Vector2(36, -306)

[node name="CollisionShape2D" type="CollisionShape2D" parent="Camera2D/Limits/LimitUp"]
position = Vector2(995, -158)
shape = SubResource("RectangleShape2D_slslj")
metadata/_edit_lock_ = true

[node name="DieZone" type="Area2D" parent="Camera2D/Limits"]
position = Vector2(970, 1242)
script = ExtResource("7_8lb55")
metadata/_edit_lock_ = true

[node name="CollisionShape2D" type="CollisionShape2D" parent="Camera2D/Limits/DieZone"]
position = Vector2(300, 0)
scale = Vector2(7.025, 7.025)
shape = SubResource("RectangleShape2D_fe4jy")
metadata/_edit_lock_ = true

[node name="DieZone2" type="Area2D" parent="Camera2D/Limits"]
position = Vector2(-102, 0)
script = ExtResource("7_8lb55")
metadata/_edit_lock_ = true

[node name="CollisionShape2D" type="CollisionShape2D" parent="Camera2D/Limits/DieZone2"]
position = Vector2(-6.00109, 507)
rotation = 1.57079
scale = Vector2(7.025, 7.025)
shape = SubResource("RectangleShape2D_ay8dg")
metadata/_edit_lock_ = true

[node name="Eraser" type="Area2D" parent="Camera2D/Limits"]
position = Vector2(-2203, 8)
script = ExtResource("5_mtntl")
metadata/_edit_lock_ = true

[node name="CollisionShape2D" type="CollisionShape2D" parent="Camera2D/Limits/Eraser"]
position = Vector2(27, 465)
shape = SubResource("RectangleShape2D_c845b")
metadata/_edit_lock_ = true

[node name="PlatGenerador" parent="Camera2D" instance=ExtResource("8_0jbxy")]
position = Vector2(3677, -249)
timeMax = 5.0

[node name="PlatGenerador2" parent="Camera2D" instance=ExtResource("8_0jbxy")]
position = Vector2(3244, 94)
timeMax = 10.0
timeMin = 3.0

[node name="PlatGenerador3" parent="Camera2D" instance=ExtResource("8_0jbxy")]
position = Vector2(2891, 418)
timeMax = 6.0
timeMin = 2.0

[node name="ItemGenerator" parent="Camera2D" instance=ExtResource("7_8tphp")]
position = Vector2(3813, -370)
timeMax = 10.0
timeMin = 5.0

[node name="ItemGenerator2" parent="Camera2D" instance=ExtResource("7_8tphp")]
position = Vector2(3441, -62)
timeMax = 3.0
timeMin = 5.0

[node name="ItemGenerator3" parent="Camera2D" instance=ExtResource("7_8tphp")]
position = Vector2(3017, 270)
timeMax = 2.0
timeMin = 3.0

[node name="Porcentaje" parent="Camera2D" instance=ExtResource("9_qlkeu")]
offset_left = 819.0
offset_top = -436.0
offset_right = 859.0
offset_bottom = -379.0

[node name="SparksUp" parent="Camera2D" instance=ExtResource("9_kegdm")]
position = Vector2(954, 434)
emitting = false
script = ExtResource("10_yihnu")

[node name="MarkPosScore" type="Marker2D" parent="Camera2D"]
position = Vector2(1337, -401)

[connection signal="comenzo" from="Player" to="Player" method="_on_comenzo"]
[connection signal="comenzo" from="Player" to="Camera2D/PlatGenerador" method="_on_player_comenzo"]
[connection signal="comenzo" from="Player" to="Camera2D/PlatGenerador2" method="_on_player_comenzo"]
[connection signal="comenzo" from="Player" to="Camera2D/PlatGenerador3" method="_on_player_comenzo"]
[connection signal="comenzo" from="Player" to="Camera2D/ItemGenerator" method="_on_player_comenzo"]
[connection signal="comenzo" from="Player" to="Camera2D/ItemGenerator2" method="_on_player_comenzo"]
[connection signal="comenzo" from="Player" to="Camera2D/ItemGenerator3" method="_on_player_comenzo"]
[connection signal="timeout" from="gameTimer" to="Player" method="_on_game_timer_timeout"]
[connection signal="body_entered" from="Camera2D/Limits/DieZone" to="Camera2D/Limits/DieZone" method="_on_body_entered"]
[connection signal="body_entered" from="Camera2D/Limits/DieZone2" to="Camera2D/Limits/DieZone2" method="_on_body_entered"]
[connection signal="body_entered" from="Camera2D/Limits/Eraser" to="Camera2D/Limits/Eraser" method="_on_body_entered"]


Good answer! There is a bit of text that has spelling errors, though, and one particular part is a bit hard to understand. This is no issue; you can just edit your post to fix it.
